# Animation working on double click not on single click

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have web page in which i want to slide the images problem is that when i double click on button it slides and on single click it does not slide i don't know why this is happening.

My Java Script for sliding

```
     <script>
            function class1(id, newclass){
                myid=document.getElementById(id);
                myid.className=newclass;
                }
            </script>

     <div id="page_three" class="panel">
     <div class="main_heading_three">DRAXXIN</div>
     <div class="menu">
           <ul>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#page_one"><img src="image/overview.gif" /></a></li>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#page_two"><img src="image/strategy.gif"/></a></li>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#page_three" onclick="class1('img_one_slide','img_one');class1('img_two_slide','img_two');"><img src="image/draxxin_active.png"/></a></li>                         <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#page_four"><img src="image/excede.gif"/></a></li>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#page_five" onclick="class1('test','img_six_2');"><img src="image/results.gif"/></a></li>
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="image/reference.gif"/></a>
                            <ul>
                            <li><a target='_blank' href="DRAXXIN-Product-Insert.pdf"><img src="image/dropdown1.png"/></a></li> 
                            <li><a target='_blank' href="DRAXXIN-Product-Insert.pdf"><img src="image/dropdown2.png"/></a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li> 
                    <li class="stix"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="rightclass_two"><img src="image/whiteslide.png"/></div>  
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="midmenu_3"><a href="#page_two"><img src="image/backward.png"/></a></li>     
                    <li class="midmenu_4"><a href="#page_four"><img src="image/forward.png"/></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>                
            <div class="text_paragraph_3">
                <p>DRAXXIN ® (<i>tulathromycin</i>) keeps working for up to 14 days.<span class="superscript">1, 2</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="text_paragraph_4">
               A single dose of DRAXXIN ® (<i>tulathromycin</i>):
                <ul><li>Controls and treats the four major BRD pathogens, including <i>Mycoplasma bovis</i></li>
                    <li>Decreases the total number of treatments</li>
                    <li>Reduces associated labor and treatment costs</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="text_paragraph_5">
                <p class="para">Pre-slaughter Withdrawal Time 18 days </p>
                <p class="para_2">IMPORTANT SAFETY INFORMATION</p>
                <p class="para_1">Do not use DRAXXIN in calves to be processed for veal. A pre-slaughter withdrawal time has not been determined for pre-ruminating calves. Effects on reproductive performance, pregnancy and lactation have not been determined. 
                </p>
           </div>
           <div class="right_text_page3">
           <p>With longer duration, DRAXXIN extends your PMIs or PTIs for a greater return on your investment.
           </p>
           </div>
           <div class="right_text_page4"> 
           <p>
           DRAXXIN has been shown to work with a 14-day PMI on high-risk cattle compared with other antimicrobials using a 3-day PMI<span class="superscript">7</span>
           </p>
           </div>
           <div class="right_text_page5"> 
           <small>
           <p>
           a,b Different superscripts identify statistically different values (P=0.0005) through 208 days.
           </p>
           <p>*Least square means.</p>
           </small>
           </div>
           <div class="right_text_page6"> 
           <p>
           A study<span class="superscript">8</span> of DRAXXIN shows, even at 7-, 10- or 14-day
           PTIs, extending the PTI resulted in no change to
           treatment responses, or slight improvement
           </p>
           </p></div>
           <div class="right_text_page7"> 
           <p>
           At 7, 10 or 14 days, there were no differences in
           mortality rate or ADG<span class="superscript">8</span>
           </p>
           <p>
           (<small><i>P=0.34</i></small>)
           </p>
           </p>
           </div>
```

These are the images for sliding .

```
        <div id="img_one_slide" class="img_one_in"><img src="image/graph_one.png"/></div>      
    <div id="img_two_slide" class="img_two_in"><img src="image/graph_two.png"/></div>

 <!--Draxxin page light box-->
```

Comment: There is no javascript in your page ?

Comment: Need to see the code you're using to do the sliding .

Comment: <li><a href="#page_three" onclick="class1('img_one_slide','img_one');class1('img_two_slide','img_two');"><img src="image/draxxin_active.png"/></a></li>                         <li class="stix"></li>

Comment: this is jquery used for sliding

Comment: <script>
                function class1(id, newclass){
                    myid=document.getElementById(id);
                    myid.className=newclass;
                    }
                </script>

Comment: @dystroy i have added javascript for sliding in my updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the href from your element a or move the onclick to another element.

As it is, the two "instructions" on the a element (the one designed by onclick, and the natural jump to href) are conflicting.

EDIT :

Here's a way (with jquery) to do both the in page jump and the sliding :

```
function doThing() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('a[name="page_three"]').offset().top + 'px'
    }, 'fast');
    class1('img_one_slide','img_one');
    class1('img_two_slide','img_two');
}



<li><img style="cursor:pointer;" src=... onclick="doThing();">
```

I added cursor:pointer; to let the user know the image is clickable.

Comment: I need to know what you try to make. Why do you have the href ? Do you want the location in page to change AND your image to slide ?

Comment: I want that when i click on Draxin button it open page and on that page it slide image at a time that's why if only give href for page then where to give onclick for sliding

Comment: Exactly,  single click is activating the link. +1'd

Comment: @vdbuilder yes how to solve or separate these and make these things done for this

Comment: edited with a solution. I used jquery to make simpler the search for the targeted position.

Comment: @dystroy thanks one thing to ask is there way to define two css files if web page is with address bar in safari it should load CSS one and if it is without address bar from icon home of ipad screen then CSS two

Comment: Not like this. You can define different css for different browsers but it's generally preferable to avoid it. Maybe a forum (or a stack overflow chat) would be easier to handle such a discussion-prone question.